# Let $(12)$ and $(23)$ be cycles. Then is $(12)(23)$ a permutation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The reason I ask this is because sometimes we talk about non-disjoint cycles, for example: $(ab)(bc) \neq (bc)(ab)$. Do we consider $(ab)(bc)$ a permutation where $f(b) = a$ and $f(b) = c$?

Comment: If $f(b)=a$ and $f(b)=c$ with $a\neq c$, then $f$ is not a function. $$(ab)(bc) = (abc).$$

Comment: $(ab)(ac)$ is the permutation gotten as a composition of those two 2-cycles. It can be written as a product of disjoint cycles. I compose functions from right to left, so I would say $$(ab)(ac)=(acb),$$ because first the 2-cycle $(ac)$ maps $a\mapsto c$, and then the 2-cycle $(ab)$ doesn't do anything to $c$, so the composition maps $a$ to $c$. You can then see that $c$ is mapped to $b$ in the composition et cetera, and can work out the presentation of the composition as a product of disjoint cycles. Beware that some people compose from left to right. @JackD'Aurizio is apparently one of them.

Comment: (cont'd) Both orders have their merits. Unless you are Polish you normally compose functions right to left, but this does run contrary to the convention of reading from left to right :-)

Comment: Great :)  Consider the permutation $(12)(3)$. It means $f(1) = 2, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 3$. Is it possible that $f^k(3) = 3 $ is in the cycle $(12)$? Suppose it is. Then either $f(1) = 3$ or $f(2) = 3$. Suppose $f(2) = 3$. But we already know $f(3) = 3$. It violates the injective property of a permutation. Contradiction, so the cycles of  $(12)(3)$ are disjoint. I need to show it for general case, but does what I wrote make sense?